# Unit testing beginner method

Tags: asp.net, unit-testing

I am currently working on a project that requires us to write unit tests.  This is an area where my knowledge is limited.  After researching over the last few days I have seen multiple examples showing how to write *basic* tests that assert if a string is equal to another string.

However, what I am still unclear on is how to approach unit testing as a whole.  I have an example method that I need to test below:

```
public static SearchResults GetSearchResults(SearchFormModel searchForm, int currentItemCount, int skip)
    {
        var results = new SearchResults();
        var client = new RestClient(Settings.Default.SearchWebServiceUrl);
        try
        {
            var request = new RestRequest("{0}", Method.GET);
            if (!searchForm.FirstName.IsNullOrEmpty()){request.AddParameter("forenames",searchForm.FirstName);}
            if (!searchForm.LastName.IsNullOrEmpty()) { request.AddParameter("surname", searchForm.LastName); }

            request.AddUrlSegment("0", "Basic");

            request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");

            var response = client.Execute<SearchResult>(request);
            if (response.ResponseStatus != ResponseStatus.Completed)
            {
                if (response.ErrorException != null)
                {
                    SendErrorEmail(response.ErrorException.Message);                        
                }
                throw new Exception(Settings.Default.SearchGenericError);
            }

            if (response.Data != null)
            {
                results.Valid = response.Data.Valid;
                var error = response.Data.Error;
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(error)){error = Settings.Default.SearchGenericError;}
                results.Error = error;
                if (response.Data.SearchResults != null)
                {                        
                    results.SearchResults = new List<SearchResult>(response.Data.SearchResults );
                }
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception(Settings.Default.SearchGenericError);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            registrantList.Error = ex.Message;
        }
        return results;
    }
```

Would a good approach here be two break this down into two separate methods? One that sets the request and gets the response like so:

```
public static SearchResults GetSearchResults(SearchFormModel searchForm, int currentItemCount, int skip)
{
    var results = new SearchResult();
    var client = new RestClient(Settings.Default.SearchWebServiceUrl);
    try
    {
        var request = new RestRequest("{0}", Method.GET);
        if (!searchForm.FirstName.IsNullOrEmpty()){request.AddParameter("forenames",searchForm.FirstName);}
        if (!searchForm.LastName.IsNullOrEmpty()) { request.AddParameter("surname", searchForm.LastName); }

        request.AddUrlSegment("0", "Basic");

        request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");

        var response = client.Execute<SearchResult>(request);
        return GetSearchResults(response);
}
```

Which in turn returns to another method which should be testable ie:

```
public static SearchResults GetSearchResults(IRestResponse<SearchResults> response)
{
    var results = new SearchResult();
    if (response.ResponseStatus != ResponseStatus.Completed)
        {
            if (response.ErrorException != null)
            {
                SendErrorEmail(response.ErrorException.Message);                        
            }
            throw new Exception(Settings.Default.SearchGenericError);
        }

        if (response.Data != null)
        {
            results.Valid = response.Data.Valid;
            var error = response.Data.Error;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(error)){error = Settings.Default.SearchGenericError;}
            results.Error = error;
            if (response.Data.SearchResults != null)
            {                        
                results.SearchResults = new List<SearchResult>(response.Data.SearchResults );
            }
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception(Settings.Default.SearchGenericError);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        registrantList.Error = ex.Message;
    }
    return results;
}
```

Apologies for the beginner question, however I want to make sure that this approach is the way to go.  Would this be the correct way to approach?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach to unit testing is to write your tests before you write the code that will make them pass. Working in this way is likely to cause you to write smaller, more easily tested classes and methods--i.e., loosely coupled code. Recall the rule of thumb that classes should have one responsibility and methods should do one thing.

If you need to get tests around the code shown here, you definitely have the right idea to break down those methods--I think there are many much smaller methods you can extract. It's hard to make a method too small if its name reveals something about the intent of what it's doing.

Are you familiar with dependency injection and mock objects libraries? Personally, I would not be writing unit tests without them (not never, surely, but not mostly). I'm not familiar with what is available in the .Net space, but the idea is that you arrange your classes to explicitly depend on various collaborators and you use the mock objects library to easily put those collaborators into exactly the right state to fully exercise your test subject. A dependency injection framework will help you to depend on interfaces rather than concrete classes--another good rule of thumb.

EDIT: Thought this answer would benefit from some more practical advice, so I remembered about [this](http://binstock.blogspot.co.at/2008/04/perfecting-oos-small-classes-and-short.html) post by Andrew Binstock on Jeff Bay's original essay "Object Calisthenics". I will understand if your initial reaction to the advice proposed there is disbelief, but I firmly believe there's no quicker way to get up to speed on the practices that you want to develop. Francesco Cirillo's [anti-if campaign](http://antiifcampaign.com/) offers yet another point of view on how to manage code complexity.

Answer (score 1):

I basically agree with @unigeek's answer. You will have to break up your classes by responsibility and then use dependency injection (DI) to mock out collaborators. Without this unit testing becomes extremely hard or impossible.

E.g., you wouldn't want a test to actually fire REST requests and send an email. So you have to extract these two responsibilities into their own classes, which you can mock.

[Mark Seemann's book on DI](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1935182501) greatly helped me to wrap my head around it.

For mocking I like to use [NSubstitute](http://nsubstitute.github.io/help/getting-started/), because I find it to be easy to use and lightweight.

Try to take your time and read up on these topics. Unit Testing is hard, but when done right it improves your code quality a lot and makes you a much better developer IMO.